# How to load a dataset with a specific structure in tfds library?

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow, dataset, cnn

I have a dataset that it's classes arranged in the following way:

```
/dataset/train/images/class1/

/dataset/train/images/class2/
.
.
.
/dataset/train/images/classN/
```

Does anyone have any idea how to store data in a *`train_ds`* variable with the help of TFDS library?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common folder structure for Image Classification, so common many libraries have a dataset class for it (torchvision, fastai, tfds), usually called `ImageFolder`.

In the case of TFDS this is implemented in the `tfds.folder_dataset.ImageFolder`:

```py
tfds.folder_dataset.ImageFolder(
    root_dir: str,
    *,
    shape: Optional[type_utils.Shape] = None,
    dtype: Optional[tf.DType] = None
)
```

As your folder already has the expected format, i.e.:

```
  split_name/  # Ex: 'train'
    label1/  # Ex: 'airplane' or '0015'
      xxx.png
      xxy.png
      xxz.png
    label2/
      xxx.png
      xxy.png
      xxz.png
  split_name/  # Ex: 'test'
```

You could just instantiate it like this:

```py
train_ds = tfds.folder_dataset.ImageFolder(
    root_dir = "/dataset/", # Note that this is a absolute path, you should use "./dataset/" or "dataset/" or "<current_working_dir_full_path>/dataset/" if that is the case.
)

# If you want a tensorflow.data.Dataset
train_ds = train_ds.as_dataset(**args)
```

Suported args for `as_dataset` method are:

```
(
    split: Optional[Union[str, tfds.core.ReadInstruction]] = None,
    batch_size: tfds.typing.Dim = None,
    shuffle_files: bool = False,
    decoders: Optional[TreeDict[decode.Decoder]] = None,
    read_config: Optional[tfds.ReadConfig] = None,
    as_supervised: bool = False
)
```

You could refer to [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/folder_dataset/ImageFolder) for details.